# SQL Self Join - one to many - with dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following two tables in sqlite:

[SQL Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGdZZ.png)

[image]

The table "Performance Indicator Table" gets populated each day with 'PerformanceIndicator' values from previous day against each site. Each site is connected to many other sites termed as site's neighbors. For instance, site A may have site C and D as its neighbors. Similarly site C can have B and itself as neighbors. These neighbor relations are defined in a mostly static "Neighbor Table".

I need to come up with a single view, joining the two tables such that we have:

[Resultant Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyHOv.png)

[image]

Please help me in coming up with the required SQL. I thought of the following:

```
select neighbors.site, neighbors.neighbor, PI_Table.* 
from neighbors 
inner join PI_Table 
   on neighbors.neighbor = PI_Table.site;
```

I am using Sqliteman to process the query and this gives me some kind of result. But exporting results in Sqliteman not responding. This may be due to number of rows. Number of rows should be:

[Number of rows in resultant view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAtkS.png)

[image]

Please let me know if it seems okay and sorry for not being able to have the images in-line.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) to understand why

Comment: How you calculate performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
select neighbors.site, neighbors.neighbor, 
       p1.*, p2.*,
       performance(..)
from neighbors 
inner join PI_Table p1
   on neighbors.site = p1.site;
inner join PI_Table p2
   on neighbors.neighbor = p2.site;
  AND p1.date = p2.date
```